# Each click add some data from object to div

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, each

I have a button and empty div in HTML.

```
<button id="add_sentence">Click here!</button>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

In JS, I have data in array

```
let data = [{ sentence: "Hi, I'm from Azerbaijan" }, {sentence: "I'm 36 years old"}, { sentence: "I learn front-end development}]
```

I need a function that when I click on button ("#add_sentence"), it takes only one sentence from array ("data")  and adds to div ("#parent").

I can add all array to empty div with 1 click. But I want 1st click adds 1st sentence. Then, 2nd click adds 2nd sentence. 3rd click adds 3rd sentence and so on.

Can anyone help?

Comment: save the number of times clicked, then feed that as the index to the array

Comment: Im new learning JS.
Can you write that code?

Comment: I think you should attempt it yourself and then come back if you get stuck and we will help debug. Won't help you learn if someone does it for you. But im sure someone will want to get free internet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data = [{ sentence: "Hi, I'm from Azerbaijan" }, {sentence: "I'm 36 years old"}, { sentence: "I learn fron-end development"}];

const button = document.querySelector("#add_sentence");
const parent = document.querySelector("#parent");

let clickCount = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (clickCount < data.length) {
    const nextSentence = document.createElement('p');
    nextSentence.innerText = data[clickCount].sentence;
    parent.appendChild(nextSentence);
    clickCount++;
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="add_sentence">Click here!</button>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learnt a lot! ^_^

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Without clickcount...

```js
var data = [{ sentence: "Hi, I'm from Azerbaijan" }, {sentence: "I'm 36 years old"}, { sentence: "I learn front-end development"}],
    prnt = document.getElementById("parent"),
    bttn = document.getElementById("add_sentence");

bttn.addEventListener("click", _ => data.length && (prnt.textContent += `${data.shift().sentence}
`));
```

```css
#parent { white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_sentence">Click here!</button>
<div id="parent"></div>
```